# HDF5 library with Jython

Tags: jython, hdf5, jython-2.7

I'm new to Jython and I would need to find a way to save scientific data in HDF5 file format.

Is there a library available with Jython or should I use a Java library directly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a library available with Jython" as opposed to "use a Java library directly". If you have found a suitable Java library, then it can be used with Jython.

Comment: I meant a python library working on Jython which I expect to be easier to use than a plain Java library.

Comment: If you were thinking about [h5py](http://www.h5py.org) then I would not expect that to work. It depends on NumPy which cannot be used in Jython (there are many questions about this on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @mzjn That was indeed my concern. Too bad.